# Android: Set items inside View from Adapter get NullPointerException

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I got a Layout and when press a Button called "Add", it add one inflated view inside this Layout and start a method to set all items inside this View (Buttons, ListView..etc).
So, I can make a list, inside the Layout, of my inflated Views and save it on Database.

My problem is, when i load the data from database, set this data on an ArrayAdapter and insert  it into the Layout,
when i call the method to set the items, i get a "NullPointerException"

This is the Activity:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_tab);

    user = new UserBean();
    username = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.et_username );
    data = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.et_data );

    formatDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

            //this is the layout
    listRecord = ( LinearLayout ) findViewById( R.id.listRecord );
    initInsertButton();

  //this is an Intent to get data from other activity and where i call the adapter to add views automatically
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        user_id = extras.getInt("id");
        data_ = extras.getString("data"); 

        accessObjectUser = new UserDAO( getApplicationContext() );
        UserBean user = accessObjectUser.oneDataById(user_id);              

        username.setText(user.getNome()+" "+user.getSobrenome());
        data.setText(data_);

        accessObjectRec = new RecordDAO ( getApplicationContext() );
        recs = accessObjectRec.recDataByUserId(user_id, data_);

        adapterRec = new RecordTagAdapter( getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.record_tag,
                rec );

        //here i set the views from adapter into layout
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapterRec.getCount(); i++) {
            View item = adapterRec.getView(i, null, null);
            listRecord.addView(item);
        }


    //here the button to add the view manually

private void initInsertButton() {


    insertRecord = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.buttonInsertRecord );
    insertRecord.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){     
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflate = ( LayoutInflater ) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            view = inflate.inflate( R.layout.record_tag, null );

            initRecTag();           
            listRecord.addView( view );

        }
    } );

}       

         //setting all items inside view added

          private void initRecTag(){        

    final TextView f_id = ( TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_food_id);
    final TextView m_id = ( TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_med_id);
    final EditText search_box = ( EditText ) view.findViewById( R.id.food_search );


    final ListView lstAlimentos = ( ListView ) view.findViewById( R.id.listView1 );

    search_box.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {           
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {       

           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                   int arg3) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
           }

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

           }
    });

    lstAlimentos.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View views, int position, long id ){
            ...
    }       


    insertHorario = ( TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_timer);
    insertHorario.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                   timeSet();                   
        }

    });


    deleteRecord = ( Button ) view.findViewById( R.id.bt_excludeRec );
    deleteRecord.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {
        View viewTemp = view;
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            listRecord.removeView(viewTemp);
        }
    } );
}


public void dataSet(){


    data.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.getTime();

            pYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            pMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            pDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



        }
    });     
}   

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        pYear = year;
        pMonth = monthOfYear;
        pDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();

    }
};


   public void updateDisplay() {
        data.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(pDay).append("-")
                    .append(pMonth + 1).append("-")                     
                    .append(pYear).append(" "));
    }



public void timeSet(){

    new TimePickerDialog( RecordTabActivity.this, t, dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();

}


TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        int hour = hourOfDay;
        int minut = minute;

        updateHour(hour, minut);
    }
};

private void updateHour(int hour, int minute) {
    insertHorario.setText( hour+":"+minute );
}


private void updateData(int year, int month, int day) {
    data.setText(day+"-"+month+"-"+day);
}
```

logcat:

```
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity     ComponentInfo{com.centeias.nutrirecord/com.centeias.nutrirecord.RecordTabActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1817)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1833)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:124)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1026)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4134)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     com.centeias.nutrirecord.RecordTabActivity.initRecTag(RecordTabActivity.java:358)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     com.centeias.nutrirecord.RecordTabActivity.onCreate(RecordTabActivity.java:254)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4411)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    at          android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1781)
09-10 19:34:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(23643):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat so we know where the NPE is?

Comment: I'd tried to inflate the laytou before or get it from Adapter, and still returning null

Comment: What is 358 of `RecordTabActivity`?

Comment: goes to "final TextView f_id = ( TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_food_id);"

Comment: Then it looks like `view` is `null`. Can you verify that with a breakpoint?

Comment: Man, I fix it, it really null, but i don't know why... so i made the view receive the child view, and it works...thanks

Comment: as a temporary solution, just check if view if null or not, if it is not null, proceed, else, return